# SQL, How to select a column from mysql with a "/" in it

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL column called `post/zip_code`.  If I try to put this into an SQL query like this:

```
SELECT post/zip_code
```

It will not read `post/zip_code` as one string.  How do I reference the name?

Comment: Use backquotes or double quotes:  `"post/zip_cod"`.

Comment: Please don't use slashes as part of database column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT `post/zip_code`
```

Wrap the column name in back ticks.

According to the MySql Documentation for schema object names:

> The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`”):

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)